# Creating Images Gallery using Java

Tags: java

Due to lack of work & knowledge, I dont know the APIs by using which I can build Images gallery.
Please suggest the Servlet/JSP APIs to display Images Gallery like Facebook / Orkut.

Answer (score 0):

Generally image galleries are done using JavaScript not using Java. Your Servlet/JSP api will provide links to your images and a JavaScript will be used to show them as gallery. [Here](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/fresh-jquery-image-gallery-display-solutions/) is a ton of jQuery plugins(There are more for other libraries and some with out using any libraries) online.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you shouldn't code it yourself :). Here you have an open source project called [TriArctic](https://sourceforge.net/projects/triarcticphoto/)  which does just that :)